# Naming pandas columns from arbitrary row data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a python script where I have read in a csv file using pandas:

```
colnames = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10']
csv_input = pd.read_csv(ifile, names=colnames)
```

The CSV file is filled with lots of uneeded junk, but the column names I want to use are defined by a row with DataName in col1.

```
csv_names = csv_input[csv_input.col1 == 'DataName']
```

The actual data is in rows with DataValue in col1, and I don't need the rest.

```
csv_input = csv_input[csv_input.col1 == 'DataValue']
```

What I'd like to do is rename the columns in csv_input with the values of csv_names, but I can't find the right syntax to do this. I have tried

```
csv_input.columns = csv_names.values
```

Which gives the error

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 10 elements, new values have 1 elements
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post more info, example data perhaps?

Comment: Show us the values of `csv_input.columns` and `csv_names.values`. I would guess that the latter is read as all-one-string due to ??, but can't debug without the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just directly assign them like so:

```
In [28]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,'e',1], 'b':[0,'f',2],'c':[0,'g',2]})
df

Out[28]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  e  f  g
2  1  2  2

In [29]:    
df.columns = df.loc[1]
df

Out[29]:
1  e  f  g
0  0  0  0
1  e  f  g
2  1  2  2
```

so in your case just do:

```
csv_input.columns = csv_names
```